# Is the realmId for a given QB company guaranteed to stay the same?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

If I have a QB company that connected in the past, and then disconnected, when they reconnect in the future, can I assume that the realmId will remain the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, yes, it will stay the same.

A simple disconnect/reconnect will not cause the realmID to change.

It *is* possible for the realmID to change for a given QuickBooks company file, but it's very rare (and likely not possible to have happen without Intuit's involvement). The only time we've seen the realmID change is when we had to have Intuit completely reset someone's sync and blow away all of the sync data.

Comment: Thanks Keith. I'll trust the RealmId then :)